# asp.net Dropdown Disable Issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a ASP.Net webpage with following **edit** rules

1. Normal user can edit only blank fields
2. Admin user can edit all fields ( No Issue!!)

To accomplish this, I tried to "**Disable**" all fields which have a value using javascipt, 
but on postback all the disabled fiels lost its state . So I change to **Readonly=true** . Now all textboxes are working as expected. But the Dropdowns can still editable even though the readonly is true .

How can i accomplish this without losing the control`s value on postback ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Wouldn't it be more intuitive with two different forms, each in separate folders with appropriate permissions on each folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the server side Enabled property.

```
MyTextBox.Enabled = false;
MyDropDownList.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: i did it using jquery

     if (source.type == "select-one") {
            if ($(source).val() == "-1") {return true;}
            $(source).hide();
            $(source).after("<span class='disp_label' <b>" + source.options[source.selectedIndex].text + "</b></span>");

Answer (score 0):

i did it using jquery

```
if (source.type == "select-one")
 { 
   if ($(source).val() == "-1") {return true;} 
   $(source).hide(); 
   $(source).after("<span class='disp_label' <b>" + source.options[source.selectedIndex].text + "</b></span>");
}
```

Thanks all